# What do I do to fix my PostgreSQL database connection problem in Django?

Tags: django, django-postgresql

I am trying to connect my Django project to a PostgreSQL database I created on AWS but I keep getting this error message each time I run `py manage.py runserver`.
Here is the error message:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: connection to server at "database-1.ce7oz69tjzjc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com" (52.3.150.111), port 5432 failed: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060)
        Is the server running on that host and accepting TCP/IP connections?
```

I followed the tutorial on w3school and followed all instructions. I created a PostgreSQL database then I updated my settings with the following:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'codekeen',
        'USER': 'baseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'database',
        'HOST': 'database-1.ce7oz69tjzjc.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com',
        'PORT': '5432'
    }
}
```

as I was told to, but I keep getting the error each time try migrating or running the server.
What do I do to fix this?

Comment: Have you verified that the database is up and running and that the connection details are correct? Have you allowed public access for the database and that it's accessible from your IP address?

Comment: Where is your Django code running? Are you running it in EC2 or some other Amazon service or are you running it on your own computer? Are you able to connect to the RDS database with `psql` or another SQL client?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure that postgresql is up and running. You can check with systemctl status postgresql-xx where xx is your postgresql version. After that,You need to allow TCP/IP connections to be able to connect postgresql database. Open the postgresql.conf file

```
vim /etc/postgresql/8.2/main/postgresql.conf
```

or

```
vim /var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf
```

And set the listen addresses to "*" or IP addresses.

```
listen_addresses='*'
```

or

```
listen_addresses='xxx.xx.x.x'
```

Comment: I think he is talking about AWS RDS postgresql .